# How to calculate the thrust of a rocket with relativistic exhaust

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, rocket-science, propulsion

The general thrust equation is $F = \frac{dm}{dt}\cdot v$, where $m$ is propellant's mass and $v$ is the exhaust velocity, is the equation right? What if the propellant is highly relativistic? One gram of propellant expelled at $290,000,000\  \text{m/s}$ should produce $290,000\ \text{N}$, according to the above equation. However, this doesn't take relativistic change into account.

What I want to know is how to calculate thrust when relativistic exhaust is involved.

Comment: Technically, the general thrust equation is $F=\dot{m}_ev_e+(p_e-p_0)A_e$ where $p_i$ are the exhaust & ambient pressures and $A_e$ the cross-sectional area of the nozzle. You've cited for the (ideal) case of $p_e=p_0$.

Comment: Just as an aside:  the $I_{sp}$ of that rocket motor would be around 29.4 ___million___ seconds (almost a whole year)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to know is the rate of change of momentum, since that is equal to the force. For a relativistic body the momentum is given by:

$$ p = \gamma mv $$

where $\gamma$ is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) and $m$ is the [rest mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) of the body. So basically just multiply your non-relativistic calculation by $\gamma$.